# What is the minimum distance from the car light in which he can bring his car to a stop?

Tags: calculus

A motorist is traveling at a constant speed V0 and is approaching a traffic light. He wishes to stop the car at the light. However, his reaction time, that is, the time it takes him to put his foot on the brakes, is T and the maximum deceleration of the braked car is a. What is the minimum distance from the car light in which he can bring his car to a stop?
The answer is supposed to be (V0²/2a) + V0T but I don't know how to get there. What I did until now was that:

a = -a

v = -at + C

V0 = -aT + C

V0 + aT = C

v = -at + V0 + aT

s = (-a/2)t² + V0t + aTt + C

0 = (-a/2)0² + V0.0 + At.0 + C

0 = C

s = (-a/2)t² + V0t + aTt

v = -at + V0 + aT

0 = -at + V0 + aT

V0 + aT = at

(V0 + aT)/a = t

Then substituting time in the "s = (-a/2)t² + V0t + aTt" equation gives us

(V0² + a²T² + 2aT)/2a

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: $s = (-a/2)t² + V_0t + aTt$ Where's your constant of integration?

Comment: Fixed, it was 0 so it doesn't change a thing and thank you btw.

Comment: Hint: that's not true. What time interval are you integrating over? Is the car's displacement 0 at the start of that interval?

Comment: what does $t=0$ represents for you ?

Comment: Well, I believe that t represents the time and yes the car displacement at the start of the interval 0 is 0. It has an initial velocity of V0 but at the interval 0 it hasn't moved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your scheme and indicating with$T$ the reaction time
and with $\Delta t$ the *following* time interval to stop
$$
\eqalign{
  & a =  - a  \cr 
  & v(t) =  - at + C  \cr 
  & v(0) = V_0  = C  \cr 
  & v(t) = V_0  - at  \cr 
  & v(\Delta t) = 0 = V_0  - a\Delta t  \cr 
  & \Delta t = V_0 /a  \cr 
  & s = V_0 T + \overline {v(t)} \;\Delta t = V_0 T + {{\left( {v(0) + v(\Delta t)} \right)} \over 2}\;\Delta t =   \cr 
  &  = V_0 T + {{\left( {V_0  + 0} \right)} \over 2}\;{{V_0 } \over a} = V_0 T + {1 \over 2}\;{{V_0 ^{\,2} } \over a} \cr} 
$$

Comment: Thank you, I was able to see my mistake but I didn't understand a few things. Why did you sum V0T to the displacement function? Where did that V0T actually come from?

Comment: until the driver actually press the brake, the car will continue with the constant initial speed (for a time T $\to s_1=V_0T$). After that the deceleration will decrease (approx. linearly)  the speed from $V_0$ to $0$ taking in $\Delta t = V_0/a$. During this time the travelled distance $s_2$ will be equal to the average speed $V_0/2$ times $\Delta t$.

Comment: Ooh, now everything makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$v^2-u^2=2as\tag{Third equation of motion}$$
Put $v=0$(final velocity), $u=v_0$(initial velocity) and $a=-a$(deceleration) for this case to get$$v_0^2=2as$$
where $s$ is the distance further travelled.

Comment: Thank you, that's it. But I wanted to solve it with the antidifferentiation method.